# Problem with sqlite database on android platform

Tags: android, sqlite

i am developing an application which uses sqlite db for storing records. I am developing this application on SDK 1.5.. when i test the application on 1.5 device it works good but when i try to run it on a 1.6 device i get a force close message with following logcat output:

03-19 09:31:35.206: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.android/com.abc.android.app}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2454)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1697)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:738)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:760)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:753)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.openOrCreateDatabase(ApplicationContext.java:473)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:193)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at **com.abc.android.DbAdapter.open(DbAdapter.java:101)**

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at **com.abc.android.class1.onCreate(class1.java:105)**

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)

03-19 09:31:35.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     ... 11 more

**DBAdapter.java**

```
public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {

        Log.d("DbAdapter", "in DbAdapter open()");

        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();        // line 101
        return this;
    }

 DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
 super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_QUERY);
 }
```

**class1.java**

```
mDB = new DbAdapter(Class1.this);
mDB.open();             // line 105
```

Please help..what do i do????

Comment: Out of curiosity are you closing the connection after?

Comment: Why inside of your `DBAdapter.java` class do you have a floating `DatabaseHelper` constructor?

Comment: Are you sure the database is created and present when in runs line 101 in DBAdapter? This `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file` may mean that it's not created yet..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `DATABASE_NAME` contains a value that is just a file name and nothing more, no slashes, etc.

Like this: 
`final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydata.db";`

And if that looks good, uninstall your app from the phone applications menu and re-install it.